# How to iterate properly nested <C:forEach> loop in jstl in java

Tags: java, foreach, jstl

I have two methods which returns two list .Now I want to display my output such as

```
row1 of list1
row1 of list2
difference in values of row1
row2 of list1
row2 of list2
difference in values of row2
```

For this I tried in this way-

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${ref.refarray_vac1(param.datepicker)}">
<c:forEach var="r" items="${ref.refernece(param.ref_logtime)}"> 

<tr bgcolor="darkgray ">
<td><c:out value="${r.logtime}"></c:out></td>

<td>
<c:choose><c:when test="${(r.beam_current) ne 0}"> 
<fmt:formatNumber value="${r.beam_current}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" pattern="##.##" var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
${(mm)}
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
${r.beam_current}</c:otherwise></c:choose></td>
</tr>

<!-- For user_selection color name-- darkkhaki -->

<tr bgcolor="cornsilk">

<td><c:out value="${row.logtime}"></c:out></td>

<td>
<c:choose><c:when test="${(row.beam_current) > 0.0}"> 
<fmt:formatNumber value="${row.beam_current}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" pattern="##.##" var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
${(mm)}
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
${row.beam_current}</c:otherwise></c:choose></td>
<tr>

<td>Deviation</td>
<td bgcolor="lime"><c:out value="${r.beam_current-row.beam_current}"></c:out></td>
```

But when I do so,I get result as-

```
row1 of list1
row1 of list2
difference in values of row1
row2 of list1
row1 of list2
difference in values of row2 and row1
```

I do not want to repeat the values which is being repeated due to outer ForEach loop tag

Answer (score 0):

I would create just one list of pairs (row from list1, row from list2) instead and use one `<c:forEach var="pairRow" items="${thePairsList}">`

Currently you have in fact nested loops.

Comment: I didn't get you.I already have two lists in java class.Can't change them.

Comment: Create a third list consisting of pairs. pair 1 contains element 1 of the first list + elemnt 1 of the second list etc.